# How to download latest MediaWiki from command line?

Tags: regular-expression, html, download, xmlstarlet, mediawiki

One can download MediaWiki via a web browser GUI here:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download

The download link there isn't version agnostic (it changes any time a new version comes out), that makes it impossible to download by the same link because the link always changes.

How could I still download the latest MediaWiki in a version agnostic way? How to "target" the dynamic download link from command line? Possibly some regex is needed but possibly not.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet` that understands HTML you can use something like this:

```
curl --silent https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download |
    xmlstarlet format -H 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//a[@class="external text" and contains(., "Download MediaWiki")]' -v '@href' -n
```

The first `xmlstarlet` line `format`s HTML into strict XML. I've discarded *stderr* because otherwise we would see a warning message that's of no relevance here. The second one parses the result to `select` the `href` attribute value from every `<a class="external text"/>` element that contains `Download MediaWiki` in its value.

Output

```
https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.38/mediawiki-1.38.4.zip
```

---

References

- [Understanding stdin, stderr and stdout in Linux](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/understanding-stdin-stderr-and-stdout-in-linux)
- [stdin, stderr, redirection and logs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129520/100397)
- [Difference between 2>&-, 2>/dev/null, |&, &>/dev/null and >/dev/null 2>&1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70963/100397)

Comment: Thank you a lot. Sadly this code is hard for me to understand, I am not a sys admin, rather a curious amateur, is there perhaps something simpler for laymen such as myself?

Comment: @automation this is a reliable solution - much more so than trying to pick out a string using a regular expression. Since you're curious (a good thing), truncate the line at the first pipe symbol and review the output in whatever way suits you. For example pipe through a pager such as `less`. Then repeat but add in the second command. The `xmlstarlet` command can be used to format and slice'n'dice XML documents. There are quite a number of [questions referencing it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet).

Comment: Well I try to take it step by step, why is the redirection to `dev/null` ("output suppression") is needed? won't we want to pipe the HTML output as-is to the second `xmlstarlet`?

Comment: I guess that understanding `sel -T -t -m` would help, sel is "select" right? Can we write select instead? What are the options?